# Почему не используют short?

Tags: java, типы-данных

Ведь лучше же. Переменные, которые влезут в диапазон -32768 - +32767 встречаются в коде часто. Short жрёт меньше оперативы, чем int. И почему-то всё равно почти не используют short. Почему?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Когда говорят о размерности типа данных, то подразумевают скорее его диапозон допустимых значений, чем количество занимаемых байт в оперативной памяти. Большинство компиляторов выравнивает значения в памяти по некоторой границе (обычно по размерности регистров процессора). Соответственно значения типа short (при размерности 16 бит) и типа int (при размерности 32 бита) в итоге займут одинаковое количество байтов в памяти (например 4 или 8 байтов).

Более того, компиляторы и виртуальные машины знают о кэшах процессоров, и могут выполнять такую оптимизацию доступа к памяти, которая приведет к тому, что одно значение будет занимать целую линию кэша (например 32 байта).

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что экономия при выборе типа данных будет заметна при сохранении данных в бинарном виде (в виде массива байт в памяти или на диске), но слабо контролируется пользователем при размещении тех же данных в памяти как переменных.

Comment: @a_gura, про такую "оптимизацию" доступа с кэшем CPU сами придумали?

--

@danpetruk, int вместо short обычно используют, чтобы 

1) не нарваться на проблемы при изменении условий задачи

2) просто меньше букв надо написать (слово int короче, чем short)

Кстати, при работе с плавающей арифметикой соображение 1) явно сильнее, чем 2) и почти всегда пишут double, а не float.

Comment: @avp Нет конечно. Такая оптимизация позволяет отчасти решать проблему false sharing.

Comment: @a_gura, ссылку на источник можете представить?

Comment: @avp Ссылку на серьезный источник дать не могу, т.к. не исследовал этот вопрос глубоко.  

Заметка в блоге Оракле, где рассказывается об аннотации @Contended (https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/entry/java_contented_annotation_to_help), с помощью которой можно рекомендовать JVM выравнивать данные при размещении в кэше.

Простой пример c выравниванием данных в кэше (http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206). Сомневаюсь, что будет просто его воспроизвести, т.к. нельзя привязать треды к конкретным ядрам в Java.

Думаю поиск по "data padding sharing" даст интересные результаты.

Comment: ARTICLES 
No Articles Found   

хитро и коварно =)

Comment: @Gorets Поправил (скобка входила в URL)

Comment: @a_gura, прямо скажу, ни в одном из Ваших примеров я не увидел, что можно потребовать (попросить) так разместить данные в памяти, чтобы **одна переменная занимала целую строку кэша**. Именно это Ваше высказывание вызвало мое недоумение.

Речь в первом примере (и ссылке из него) идет об управлении **группированием** переменных, которое очевидно приводит к тому, что (в результате выравнивания) некоторые из них будут попадать в разные строки кэша.

Из этого совершенно не следует, что другие переменные не будут размещены в тех же cash-lines.

В любом случае речь об явном управлении размещением.

Comment: @avp Одна переменная или несколько - неважно. Важно то, что размещение в памяти может быть совершенно другим ради некоторых оптимизаций. Соответственно для случая с одной переменной мы можем разместить ее так, чтобы она занимала в памяти размер кэшлайна (заполнив нужный объем некоторым значением).

Первый пример говорит не только о группировке переменных, но и об их изоляции таким образом, чтобы они не попали в один кэшлайн (см. пример C из поста).

Что касается непомеченных переменных, то я о них ничего не утверждаю. Но такая оптимизация в теории может быть сделана и без ведома пользователя.

Comment: @a_gura, 

     для случая с одной переменной мы можем разместить ее так, чтобы она занимала в памяти размер кэшлайна (заполнив нужный объем некоторым значением).

Вот это совершенно верно. Только к вопросу (**почему не используют short?**) отношения не имеет.

Comment: Компилятор не может знать о размере кеша процессора, при компиляции не известны свойства машины-клиента.

Answer (score 2):

Использование `short` для *одиночной* переменной очень часто лишено смысла: размер `int` обычно подобран наиболее эффективным образом (в языках, которые допускают переменный размер), так что оперирование с `int` наиболее выгодно.

Есть, однако, случаи, когда количество памяти, занимаемое переменной, имеет значение: это случай *массива*. Здесь для экономии памяти может оказаться уместным использование более "коротких" типов данных.

Почему же `short` редко используют? Наверное потому, что сейчас оперативная память достаточно велика, и экономия памяти не настолько важна.

Comment: Совершенно не лишено смысла использование переменной типа short, если нужно ограничинить ОДЗ этой самой переменной.

Совершенно не факт, что каждое значение одной ячейки массива будет занимать памяти, соответствующую размерности типа.

Comment: @a_gura: можете привести конкретный пример, когда именно размер памяти, занимаемый конкретно массивом, не равен (размер типа элемента) * (количество элементов) + О(1)? Или это произвольное предположение?

Comment: @a_gura: ограничение значений в большинстве языков не контролируется в рантайме. Так что вы получите тот же ответ, если проведёте вычисления в `int` (то есть по модулю, скажем, 2^32), и лишь конечный результат обрежете до размера `short`.

Comment: @a_gura, 

    Совершенно не факт, что каждое значение одной ячейки массива будет занимать памяти, соответствующую размерности типа.


а вот это уже неверно. Если для одиночной переменой (особенно в Java) можно представить, что ее размер (точнее выравнивание) не совпадает с минимумом, определяемым диапазоном значений типа, то для массива **размер имеет значение**.

Иначе, что Вы собираетесь делать с native methods и спецификацией их интерфейса с JVM?

Comment: @VladD Зачем использовать дополнительные манипуляции с int, если можно просто использовать short.

Comment: @VladD, еще раз пошучу - short используется реже, поскольку его набивать дольше.

Comment: @VladD Компиляторы бывают разные, например JIT.

@avp отвечаю на коммент из треда выше, т.к. там больше нельзя оставлять комменты.

К вопросу это имеет непосредственное отношение, т.к. развивает в ответе идею паддинга.

Comment: @a_gura: потому что `int` быстрее? Не потребуется каждый раз обрезать результат операций (арифметика выполняется часто в `int`). я не настаиваю на том, что это лучше (без профилирования давать гарантии нельзя, разумеется!), я пытаюсь объяснить, почему `int` чаще используется.

Comment: @VladD @avp На счет массива переврал. Прошу прощения. Перепутал совершенно с другой идеей оптимизации.